# GE profile cooking range traditional glass cooktop not working properly

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have GE profile traditional glass cooktop [image]

as you can see in the smaller yellow square, only the inside circle should turn red. But the outside circle turns red first.

Could you suggest -

1. what could be causing this problem amd what part should i buy to fix it? parts are available at this [site](https://www.partselect.com/Models/JP989BK1BB/)
2. how much would it cost to fix it?
3. should i buy a new range - everything except below is working fine

-----------update 1 - adding model number

JP989BK1BB General Electric Cooktop - Overview

parts are available at this [site](https://www.partselect.com/Models/JP989BK1BB/)

-----------------update 2 ---requesting part numbers for remaining switches

as i am going to replace one switch, i am thinking of replacing remaining 3 too. Could you take a look and let me know the part number? would i need 3 of Infinite Control Switch/ part 19 ?

Comment: The photo is quite small. What does the light indicate?

Comment: Your cost and "should I" questions are off topic as price-related and opinion-based, respectively.

Comment: what happens when you turn the switch to the  right side?

Comment: when i turn the switch to right side outer circle and inner circle get the power supply and they turn red. But the inner circle takes some time to get hot as compared to the outer circle

Comment: Are you sure that's an induction cooktop? That looks more like a traditional glass cooktop.   Since so many things are computer controlled today, the first thing I'd try is turning off the breakers for a few minutes, then turn it back on. It's unlikely to solve the problem, but it's an easy step to take. More likely it's a bad switch.

Comment: i already switched on and off my breakers - that didnt help. It is a traditional glass cooktop indeed...i made a mistake earlier...could you suggest which switch i should buy? i have provided link for parts in the updated part of my question

Comment: @user2543622 - it looks like part number 20, "Dual burner control switch". But before you spend $70 on a replace switch, you can test it with a multimeter if you can find a wiring diagram for the stove or switch. A couple people on the [product page for the switch](https://www.partselect.com/PS236785-GE-WB24T10063-Dual-Burner-Control-Switch.htm?SourceCode=20&SearchTerm=JP989BK1BB&ModelNum=JP989BK1BB&ModelID=382950) said they had the same problem as you before replacing the swtich.

Comment: those control switches are completely mechanical .... there is no electronic component to them ..... couple of the contacts have shorted together ...... replace the switch

Comment: which switch @jsotola? do you agree with the Johny's comment above?

Comment: the control switch in the small yellow square

Comment: the control assembly has one wire connected to  AC power, and two other wires going to the two elements ..... there may be a thin wire that controls the `HOT` indicator light ..... take pictures of the control and the wiring, or write down which wire is connected to what ...... disconnect all wires .... use an ohm-meter to  find out if the two switches inside the control are operating normally

Comment: could you reply my updated question? @Johnny

Comment: could you reply my updated question? @jsotola

Comment: @user2543622, why? there is nothing to add ...... 1. has already been determined .... 2. it is up to you to find out the cost of the control .... 3. really? if i tell you to replace the range, then you will?

Comment: @jsotola could you reply to questions below text " -----------------update 2 ---requesting part numbers for remaining switches"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP said he already tried power cycling it just in case it was some transient controller problem, so my next best guess would be that the switch is bad.

It looks like it's the switch marked part number 20 *"Dual Burner Control Switch*" on the [product diagram](https://www.partselect.com/Models/JP989BK1BB/Sections/COOKTOP/?ModelID=382950&ModelNum=JP989BK1BB&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=2&Selected=00123860i01&Position=1&mfg=GE&Type=Cooktop&Mark=1) on the parts page he linked to. Several people on the comments page for that switch said they had the same problem before replacing the switch -- the burner stays on high.

If a wiring diagram of the stove (or switch) is available, you should be able to test the switch with a multimeter. [This site](https://www.partselect.com/Range-Stove-Oven+Infinite-Switch-Testing+repair.htm) gives some guidelines, basically you're just testing for continuity between the switched terminals. With a switch like this that has multiple outputs (and possibly an independent indicator light output), it would be difficult to test it without knowing which terminal is which.

Comment: any estimate on how long it would take to replace that part? i would like to know so that if a  handyman provides time estimate then i would know whether the estimate is reasonable or not

Comment: No idea, it took me all day to replace an igniter in my stove because I had to take apart most of the oven to get to it (an experienced repairman could have certainly done it in less time). I can't tell from the diagrams how easy it is to open the top panel to get to your switch, it's probably relatively simple but it's hard to say so for sure without seeing it. On my gas stove I can open the top surface by removing a couple screws so the total repair time would be  30 minutes or so assuming the switch is an exact replacement. But your electric stove is likely different.

Comment: as i am going to replace one switch, i am thinking of replacing remaining 3 too. COuld you take a look and let me know the part number? thanks

Comment: would i need 3 of Infinite Control Switch/ part 19
?